# Is it possible to have multiple <template> areas defined in a custom control in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I currently have:

```
<uc:MyControl ...>
<Template>
</Template>
</uc:Mycontrol>
```

I would like

```
<uc:MyControl ...>
<FishBiscuit>
html
</FishBiscuit>
<FishBiscuit>
html
</FishBiscuit>
<FishBiscuit>
html
</FishBiscuit>
<FishBiscuit>
html
</FishBiscuit>
.
.
.
```

However I'm not sure if it's possible, or how to wire it up if it is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It really seems impossible with the approach you choose. The next markup

```
<uc:MyControl runat="server">
    <FishBiscuit>
        html1
    </FishBiscuit>
    <FishBiscuit>
        html2
    </FishBiscuit>
</uc:MyControl>
```

should instanciate only the last template (`html2` value) if you use `public ITemplate FishBiscuit` property of your custom control. So, there are two approaches:

- to use different properties as
  [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170743/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-template-areas-defined-in-a-custom-control-in-a/5170999#5170999) said,
- or use a control like
  [`MultiView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.multiview.aspx) for your purposes.

See, the markup you posted above could be transformed to:

```
<asp:MultiView runat="server">
    <asp:View runat="server">
        html
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View runat="server">
        html
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View runat="server">
        html
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View runat="server">
        html
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

which is closer to the markup proposed by you.

Answer (score 0):

They have to be different properties:

```
[
PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty),
TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)
]
public ITemplate FishBiscuit { get; set; }

[
PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty),
TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)
]
public ITemplate FishBiscuit2 { get; set; }
```

Each template defined above translates to a property, so it has to have a matching property name.

HTH.